# XPath, XSL: How to select all nodes, not just elements, when xsl:param is a node-set?

Tags: xslt, xpath

In an XSL recursion, this

```
<xsl:with-param name="items" select="$items[position() > 1]
```

would normally work to recurse with all nodes but the first. But it only works if the nodes are elements. If they are a mix of element and text nodes, the recursion fails, since, for example, $items[3] returns the third element node, not the third node, regardless whether text or element.

So the expression sets the new $items to just the element nodes in the old $items. The text nodes are lost.

Comment: . . . or is this a misbehavior by xsltproc?

Comment: Works fine for me (tested using xsltproc). How did you exactly test? Could you include example XSLT and input? Specifically, what kind of XPath expression did you use to select the node set in `$items` (remember that `*` selects element nodes only)? -- I tested with this stylesheet: http://pastebin.com/f2e45f9a7 and this input: http://pastebin.com/f1375f5c1

Comment: Argh, good point. I did select with *. That would explain it. My blunder. Thanks!

Comment: @Juka, you could paste your comment as an answer so that we could file this question as answered.